How to perform Faster Object detection on webcam using onnx runtime web?
This is the javascript script which is performing object detection accurately but processing is taking time which creates lags in frames.There is no smoothness in it.
This is the script from some code I followed.
<script>
    var video_Element = document.getElementById("videoElement");
    var session = null;
    var arraybuffer = null;
    var modelPromise = null;

    async function fillarraybuffer() {
        var modelPath = "api/Models/TestSeven";
        console.log(`Loading model from ${modelPath}`);

        try {
            var response = await fetch(modelPath);
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`Failed to fetch model from ${modelPath}: ${response.statusText}`);
            }
            arraybuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
            //modelPromise = ort.InferenceSession.create(arraybuffer);

            modelPromise = ort.InferenceSession.create(arraybuffer, {
                executionProviders: ['wasm'],
                wasmPaths: {
                    'ort-wasm.wasm': 'js/ort-wasm.wasm',
                    'ort-wasm-simd.wasm': 'js/ort-wasm-simd.wasm',
                    'ort-wasm-simd-threaded.wasm': 'js/ort-wasm-threaded.wasm'
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error loading model:", error);
        }
    }

    fillarraybuffer();

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then(stream => {
            video_Element.srcObject = stream;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error accessing webcam:", error);
        });

    var detectButton = document.getElementById("detectButton");

    detectButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
        detectButton.disabled = true;
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = video_Element.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = video_Element.videoHeight;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");



        const detectFrame = async () => {

            ctx.drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            const imageBlob = await new Promise(resolve => canvas.toBlob(resolve, 'image/jpeg'));
            const boxes = await detect_objects_on_image(imageBlob);
            draw_image_and_boxes(imageBlob, boxes);

            requestAnimationFrame(detectFrame); // Detect objects in the next frame
        };

        detectFrame();

        // var lastFrameTime = 0;
        // //1700 best so far
        // var frameDelay = 1200; // Delay in milliseconds between frames

       
        // var detectFrame = async (timestamp) => {
        //     if (timestamp - lastFrameTime < frameDelay) {
        //         requestAnimationFrame(detectFrame);
        //         return;
        //     }
        //     lastFrameTime = timestamp;

        //     ctx.drawImage(video_Element, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        //     var imageBlob = await new Promise(resolve => canvas.toBlob(resolve, 'image/jpeg'));
        //     var boxes = await detect_objects_on_image(imageBlob);
        //     draw_image_and_boxes(imageBlob, boxes);

        //     requestAnimationFrame(detectFrame);
        // };

        // requestAnimationFrame(detectFrame);
    });

    function draw_image_and_boxes(file, boxes) {
        console.log("Drawing image and boxes");
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        img.onload = () => {
            var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#00FF00";
            ctx.lineWidth = 3;
            ctx.font = "18px serif";
            boxes.forEach(([x1, y1, x2, y2, label]) => {
                ctx.strokeRect(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
                ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
                var width = ctx.measureText(label).width;
                ctx.fillRect(x1, y1, width + 10, 25);
                ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
                ctx.fillText(label, x1, y1 + 18);
            });
        };
    }

    async function detect_objects_on_image(buf) {
        try {
            var [input, img_width, img_height] = await prepare_input(buf);
            var output = await run_model(input);
            return process_output(output, img_width, img_height);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error detecting objects:", error);
            return [];
        }
    }

    async function prepare_input(buf) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = URL.createObjectURL(buf);
            img.onload = () => {
                var [img_width, img_height] = [img.width, img.height];
                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width = 640;
                canvas.height = 640;
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 640, 640);
                var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 640, 640);
                var pixels = imgData.data;

                var red = [], green = [], blue = [];
                for (let index = 0; index < pixels.length; index += 4) {
                    red.push(pixels[index] / 255.0);
                    green.push(pixels[index + 1] / 255.0);
                    blue.push(pixels[index + 2] / 255.0);
                }
                var input = [...red, ...green, ...blue];
                resolve([input, img_width, img_height]);
            };
        });
    }

    async function run_model(input) {
        try {
            var model = await modelPromise;
            input = new ort.Tensor(Float32Array.from(input), [1, 3, 640, 640]);
            var outputs = await model.run({ images: input });
            return outputs["output0"].data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error running model:", error);
            return [];
        }
    }



     function process_output(output, img_width, img_height) {
        let boxes = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < 8400; index++) {
            var [class_id, prob] = [...Array(80).keys()]
                .map(col => [col, output[8400 * (col + 4) + index]])
                .reduce((accum, item) => item[1] > accum[1] ? item : accum, [0, 0]);
            if (prob < 0.5) continue;
            var label = yolo_classes[class_id];
            var xc = output[index];
            var yc = output[8400 + index];
            var w = output[2 * 8400 + index];
            var h = output[3 * 8400 + index];
            var x1 = (xc - w / 2) / 640 * img_width;
            var y1 = (yc - h / 2) / 640 * img_height;
            var x2 = (xc + w / 2) / 640 * img_width;
            var y2 = (yc + h / 2) / 640 * img_height;
            boxes.push([x1, y1, x2, y2, label, prob]);
        }

        boxes = boxes.sort((box1, box2) => box2[5] - box1[5]);
        var result = [];
        while (boxes.length > 0) {
            result.push(boxes[0]);
            boxes = boxes.filter(box => iou(boxes[0], box) < 0.7);
        }
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    }



    function iou(box1, box2) {
        return intersection(box1, box2) / union(box1, box2);
    }

    function union(box1, box2) {
        var [box1_x1, box1_y1, box1_x2, box1_y2] = box1;
        var [box2_x1, box2_y1, box2_x2, box2_y2] = box2;
        var box1_area = (box1_x2 - box1_x1) * (box1_y2 - box1_y1);
        var box2_area = (box2_x2 - box2_x1) * (box2_y2 - box2_y1);
        return box1_area + box2_area - intersection(box1, box2);
    }

    function intersection(box1, box2) {
        var [box1_x1, box1_y1, box1_x2, box1_y2] = box1;
        var [box2_x1, box2_y1, box2_x2, box2_y2] = box2;
        var x1 = Math.max(box1_x1, box2_x1);
        var y1 = Math.max(box1_y1, box2_y1);
        var x2 = Math.min(box1_x2, box2_x2);
        var y2 = Math.min(box1_y2, box2_y2);
        return (x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1);
    }

    var yolo_classes = [
        '.', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '-', 'kwh'
    ];
</script>

The problem is there is a slight lag or no smoothness in frames.
The good is that it detects and accuracy is great to 90+ percent.
For faster frames I tried worker on it. Where webcam run normally but drawing boxes were drawn on updated frames not the frames at input time. Worker visually presents slow drawn bounding boxes and bring accuracy at 80.
Just an example be if object is at X axis = 10 and passed as input after slow performing it detects with boxes at X= 10 but the object has slightly moved to X axis= 12 or 13 due to constantly updates of frames which bounding boxes processing is done on.
Can functions of his code be made more efficient so no lags occurs. Also tried intervals for processing but did not work too.
